# How do I serialize and extract the schemas from c# XmlSchemaSet?

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a XmlSchemaSet member in my class which I want to serialize and also extract the schemas inside it.
how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset_members.aspx) shows there's a `schemas()` member which returns a Collection of `XmlSchema`s, which you can `Write()` anywhere you like.